# How to assign a value to a radiobutton in pyqt?

Tags: assign, qradiobutton

I want to assign a value to a radiobutton when it is checked.

```py
def radiobutton8(self):
    if self.radioButton_8.isChecked():
        self.radioButton_8 = 02
```

However, this cannot work. Any solution?

UPDATE: My code has been edited to be:

```py
class MyRadioButton(QtGui.QRadioButton):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyRadioButton, self).__init__()
        self.value = None

    def SetValue(self, val):
        self.value = val

    def GetValue(self):
        return self.value

class UserTool(QtGui.QDialog):
    def setup(self, Dialog):
                          ...
        self.radioButton_8.toggled.connect(self.radiobutton8)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
                          ...
        self.radioButton_8 = MyRadioButton()
        self.radioButton_8.setText(_translate("Dialog", "A1", None))

def radiobutton8(self):
    if self.radioButton_8.isChecked():
        value = self.radioButton_8.setValue("02")
        self.lcdNumber.display(value)
```

However, my original text 'A1' for the radio button is now missing and my number still does not appear on my lcd when checked. Any idea why?

UPDATE: I edited my code to  be something like that:

```py
class MyRadioButton(QtGui.QRadioButton):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyRadioButton, self).__init__()
        self.value = None

    def SetValue(self, val):
        self.value = val

    def GetValue(self):
        return self.value

class UserTool(QtGui.QDialog):
    def setup(self, Dialog):
                  ...
        self.lcdNumber = QtGui.QLCDNumber(Dialog)
        self.lcdNumber.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 10, 71, 23))
        self.lcdNumber.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.lcdNumber.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lcdNumber"))
        self.lcdNumber.setStyleSheet("* {background-color: black; color: white;}")
        self.lcdNumber.display('00')

        self.radioButton_8 = QtGui.QRadioButton(Dialog)
        self.radioButton_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 10, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton_8.setChecked(False)
        self.radioButton_8.setAutoExclusive(False)
        self.radioButton_8.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("radioButton_8")) 
        self.radioButton_8 = MyRadioButton()
        self.radioButton_8.setText("A1")
        self.radioButton_8.setValue(02)
        self.radioButton_8.toggled.connect(self.showValueFromRadioButtonToLCDNumber)

    def showValueFromRadioButtonToLCDNumber(self):
        value = self.radioButton_8.GetValue()
        if self.radioButton_8.isChecked():
            self.lcdNumber.display(value)
```

And then now I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Vivien Phua/Documents/Python Scripts/Rs232.py", line 303, in handleOpenWidget
    self.popup = UserTool()
  File "C:/Users/Vivien Phua/Documents/Python Scripts/Rs232.py", line 39, in __init__
    self.setup(self)
  File "C:/Users/Vivien Phua/Documents/Python Scripts/Rs232.py", line 153, in setup
    self.radioButton_8.setValue(02)
AttributeError: 'MyRadioButton' object has no attribute 'setValue'
```

I have also tried the code you have given me and there is no such error, but the LCD in your code does not show the value 02.

Comment: For your second UPDATE error: it is suppose to be SetValue, not setValue. Code I gave you shows 2, if you want it to show 02 set that value as string: `self.radioButton_8.SetValue("02")` instead of `self.radioButton_8.SetValue(02)` . I've updated that in my answer in EDIT2, but if you take a look I've also mentioned it in EDIT1

Comment: I tried to run your code in EDIT2 and made sure it is   self.radioButton.SetValue("02") but it still doesn't work. Nothing happens when I checked the radio button.

Comment: Oh it worked! I deleted this line `self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.showValueFromRadioButtonToLCDNumber)` and added `self.radioButton.toggled.connect(self.showValueFromRadioButtonToLCDNumber)` and it worked. However is there anyway way to revert the LCD display if radio button is checked then unchecked?

Comment: showValueFromRadioButtonToLCDNumber will be called every time you check or uncheck radiobutton. So you can set LCD if self.radioButton_8.isChecked() and revert it otherwise. You can simply clear it or you will need some logic to save previous value of LCD if you want to show previous value.

Comment: if you have problems doing it, post it as a new question

Comment: No need to create a new class here. It is Python! Just add a new attribute to your radiobutton. `self.radioButton_8.myvalue = 123`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean text value next to radioButton? if so, here is solution:

```
def radiobutton8(self):
    if self.radioButton_8.isChecked():
        self.radioButton_8.setText("02")
```

**EDIT1**:
radioButton doesn't have value field as you need. 
However, you can write your own radiobButton class that inherits original QRadioButton, and add that field. Example:

```
class MyRadioButton(QtGui.QRadioButton):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyRadioButton, self).__init__()
        self.value = None

    def SetValue(self, val):
        self.value = val

    def GetValue(self):
        return self.value
```

and use it like this:

```
self.radioButton_8 = MyRadioButton()
self.radioButton_8.setText("some text")
...
def radiobutton8(self):
    if self.radioButton_8.isChecked():
        self.radioButton_8.SetValue("02")# or .SetValue(2) if you want it to be integer
```

**EDIT2**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt

class MyRadioButton(QtGui.QRadioButton):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyRadioButton, self).__init__()
        self.value = None

    def SetValue(self, val):
        self.value = val

    def GetValue(self):
        return self.value

class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.pushButton_7 = QtGui.QPushButton("if RB is checked, show it's value to LCD")
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 650, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.showValueFromRadioButtonToLCDNumber)

        self.radioButton = MyRadioButton()
        self.radioButton.setText("some text")
        self.radioButton.SetValue("02")# somewhere in code first set value to radio button

        self.lcdNumber = QtGui.QLCDNumber()

        self.layout.addWidget(self.pushButton_7)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.radioButton)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lcdNumber)

    def showValueFromRadioButtonToLCDNumber(self):
        value = self.radioButton.GetValue()
        if self.radioButton.isChecked():
            self.lcdNumber.display(value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: No, what I mean is I want to add a value to the radio button like a function. I want the value to appear on LcdNumber widget to show the number '02' when I check the radio button. Any solution for this?

Comment: take a look at Edit in my answer

Comment: first you need to set value of radio button in order to read it with `GetValue()`. Take a look at working example in **EDIT2** in my answer. As for setText, I don't know what your `_translate` method do

Comment: The _translate is just a command generated by PyQt4 when i generated the Python script after dragging and dropping the widgets on my UI. I tried your suggestion but there is no need for a pushbutton. Instead, I edited mine to become like this shown above.

Comment: setText method needs string (QString) as input parametar, so ensure that _translate returns that type